# Google Scripts Как написать скрипт при работе с таблицами?

Tags: google-apps-script

Я новичок в google scripts и мне нужна помощь в написании скрипта для sheets.

Есть таблица **A** и есть таблица **B**. В таблице **A** есть несколько колонок, в каждой колонке разная информация.

Мне нужно, чтобы: 
 1. Команда искала определенное слово в таблице **A** (например "Петя") - в колонке G; 
 2. копировала полностью строку, в которой содержится это слово 
 3. вставляла эту строку в таблицу **B** в последнюю свободную строку

Условие такое, что эти таблицы можно использовать только по ссылке ибо они находятся в разных папках:) Подобные разборы в сети не нашла, поэтому очень нужна ваша помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Например так. За оптимальность кода не ручаюсь.
[Таблица А](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r4gg44ML36Vhaih22YjFvuoMygxMpCB2nd7BJOa2bDQ/edit?usp=sharing)
[Таблица В](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7wFjSwAugRsn_jZnkZc9hLhX2K9ov6hYED21CKSFN4/edit?usp=sharing)
Код в таблице В

```
function myFunction1(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('сюда вставить Url источника');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('сюда вставить имя листа источника');
  var r = sh.getDataRange();
  var v = r.getValues();

  var shc1 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('сюда вставить Url получающей таблицы').getSheetByName('сюда вставить имя листа получающей таблицы');
  var rc1 = shc1.getRange('A1'); //ячейка с условием отбора
  var vc1 = rc1.getValue();

  var filterV = v.filter(function(row){
    return row[6] == vc1;
  });

  var lastrow = shc1.getLastRow();
  shc1.getRange(lastrow+1, 2, filterV.length,filterV[0].length).setValues(filterV); 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, работает. Но появился еще один вопрос. У меня скрипт выдает ошибку после того, как не находит в таблице-источник данные. Хотелось бы чтобы скрипт это игнорировал и выполнял следующую строку. Например, поставщик Р3Д3 - его нет в вашей таблице, поэтому скрипт выдаст ошибку и не пойдет искать следующего поставщика. Как это сделать на примере ваших таблиц?